# Как настроить график с группировкой дат по неделям в Google data studio?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-data-studio

Есть исходная таблица с ежедневно добавляемыми данными. Надо **суммировать (сгруппировать) эти данные по неделям и отобразить в графике** их динамику.

*Вариант создания 4 графиков (на каждую неделю по одному) не предлагайте.*

Знаю, что есть в отчетах вычисляемые поля. Взможно с их помощью можно реализовать желаемое?

Подскажите как сделать эту группировку по неделям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В любой области источника данных нажмите "*Edit data source*"

[image: Edit data source. Data Studio]

2. В редакторе найдите кнопку "*Add a field*"
3. В редакторе формул введите `WEEK(date)`, где `date` - это поле даты с типом даты. Если такого поля нет, то вы должны в функцию `WEEK` добавить вторым аргументом тип строки, которую необходимо распарсить для получения даты.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Используйте поле для создания графиков
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Вы не должны менять "*Date Range Dimension*", если у вас поле `date` имеет тип даты. Это вам позволит применять "*Data Range*" для `week`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]